# Get ID of ajax response's root element

Tags: jquery, ajax

My ajax response is dynamically created, and it can be either:

```
<div id="one">Test One</div>
```

or

```
<div id="two">Test Two</div>
```

I know how to get the element from ajax response by ID, but what if I don't know the ID and want to check it?

I'm trying to get it like the below, but both console.logs outputs "undefined":

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'file.php',
  success: function(result)
    {
      console.log ($(result).get(0).id);  // undefined
      console.log ($(result).attr('id')); // undefined
    }
  });
```

Comment: What is the output of `result`? Literally `<div id="two">Test Two</div>`? If it is, both your methods should work.

Comment: result, is usually a json response, so $(result) will not do anything helpful for you, try result[id] - if the json response is a string then you will have to convert to an object first (result=$.parseJSON(result)) and then you can do result[id]

Comment: @putvande the result in console "Response" looks like: <!-- comment --> <div id="two"><div class="container"><other html tags></div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll receive that as a string, so first you parse it:

```
var parsed = $($.parseHTML(result));
```

...then you get the `id` from the first element in the resulting jQuery object:

```
var id = parsed.first().attr("id");
// or
var id = parsed[0].id; // If you know for sure there will be at least one element
```

**Update**: In a comment you've said that it may have a comment in front of it, e.g.

```
 <!-- comment --> <div id="two">...</div>
```

rather than just

```
 <div id="two">...</div>
```

If so, you need to get the `id` slightly differently by taking the first *element* (skipping comment nodes, which you'll have in the jQuery object if parsed like the above):

```
var id = parsed.filter("*").first().attr("id");
```

The `filter` only matches elements, not comment or text nodes.

**Live Example**:

```js
function success(result) {
  var parsed = $($.parseHTML(result));
  log("ID is " + parsed.filter("*").first().attr("id"));
}

success('<!-- blah blah --><div id="one">Test One</div>');
success('<div id="two">Test Two</div>');

function log(msg) {
  $("<p>").text(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note: You *can* parse it by just passing the string directly to [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), but if the string doesn't "look like" HTML accoring to jQuery's auto-detection, it may try to interpret the string as a CSS selector instead. That's why we have [`$.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/), to be un-ambiguous.